# Unknown error while creating table in SQL notebook

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, data-analysis, create-table

Im trying to create a table by using the following syntax in SQL notebook, but keep getting an error like: " Expected list-item: "
my code:

```html
create table
   player_info as 
( 
select distinct id,
         name,
         sex,
         age,
         case(when height is NULL then floor(avg(height)) else height end) as Hght,
         case(when weight is NULL then floor(avg(weight)) else weight end ) as Wght,
         team as country,
         city
from athlete_events
group by id,
         name,
         sex,
         age
)
```

for example, I want to create a table using the field mentioned in the select clause from the main dataset so I can **remove NULL values** . The expected output should be a table where there are no null values in age, height and weight column.

> **Edited : I found the solution to this problem, it was actually the parenthesis which were problem for case statment as well as select clause, it shouldn't be included in parenthesis, it considers that as part of subquery.  Also which considering condition i used 'NA' as the dtype for that column is TEXT.  The code should look like below :**

```html
create table
   player_info as 

select distinct id,
         name,
         sex,
         age,
         (case when height ='NA' then floor(avg(height)) else height end) as Hght,
         (case when weight ='NA' then floor(avg(weight)) else weight end ) as Wght,
         team as country,
         city
from athlete_events
group by id,
         name,
         sex,
         age
```

Comment: Error msg: 'expected-list: < result-column >'

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result ..

Answer (score 0):

Program is complaining about the outermost parentheses here:

```
 case(when height is NULL then floor(avg(height)) else height end) as Hght,
```

The next line needs to be corrected also. `CASE` is an expression, not a function. You can review the proper syntax in [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

And beware that this will not accomplish the stated goal. The subquery essentially works on one `id` at a time. If the height or weight in a particular row is NULL, `floor(avg(height))` will be 0.

Comment: thank you I learned the case syntax that improved my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

No parentheses are allowed between the `case` and the `when`.  Instead of:

```
     case(when height is NULL then floor(avg(height)) else height end) as Hght,
     case(when weight is NULL then floor(avg(weight)) else weight end ) as Wght,
```

Use:

```
     (case when height is NULL then floor(avg(height)) else height end) as Hght,
     (case when weight is NULL then floor(avg(weight)) else weight end ) as Wght,
```

I sincerely doubt that this does what you really want . . . `height` and `weight` are not in the `group by`.  In fact, I doubt the `group by` is needed at all and you really intend:

```
select id, name, sex, age,
       coalesce(height, floor(avg(height) over ()),
       coalesce(weight, floor(avg(weight) over ())
       team as country, city
from athlete_events
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up creating table without doing the avg or changing the NULL value, but I updated table later on that worked for me this time.